# File encryption and desryption using AES scala

Tags: java, scala, encryption, cryptography, aes

Am using the below code to encrypt and decrypt a file. Am able to encrypt it. But could not decrypt. Could someone help me on what is wrong with the below code

```
import java.io.{File, FileInputStream, FileOutputStream}
import java.util.Base64
import java.nio.file.{Files, Paths}
import java.security.{KeyFactory, KeyStore, PrivateKey, PublicKey, SecureRandom}
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec

import javax.crypto.{Cipher, KeyGenerator, SecretKey}
import javax.crypto.spec.{IvParameterSpec, SecretKeySpec}

object Utils extends App {
  val jksFileLocation = "jksPath"
  val jksPwd = "x@123"
  val privatePwd = "x@123"
  val certAlias = "x"
  val publicKeyFilePath = "pathTopub.key"
  val inputFile = "pathToInpFile"
  val outputFile = "PathToEncryptFile"
  val decryptFile = "PathToDecryptFile"

  encryptData(inputFile, outputFile)

  decryptData(outputFile, decryptFile)

  val decryptedData = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(decryptFile)))

  def encryptData(inputFilePath: String, outputFilePath: String): Unit = {
    val inp = new FileInputStream(inputFilePath)
    val file = new File(outputFile)
    if(!file.exists()) file.createNewFile()
    val out = new FileOutputStream(outputFilePath)
    val publicKey = getPublicKeyFromFile(publicKeyFilePath)
    println("Public key extracted from file "+ publicKey)
    val AESKey = generateAESKey()
    val outBytesAES = getEncryptedAESKeyBytes(publicKey, AESKey)
    println("Length of AES key bytes" + outBytesAES.length)
    val ivTuple = generateIV()
    println("length of iv "  + ivTuple._2.length)
    println("printing iv byte array data ")
    ivTuple._2.foreach(println(_))
    val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding")
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, AESKey, ivTuple._1)
    out.write(outBytesAES)
    out.write(ivTuple._2)
    processFile(cipher, inp, out, "encrypt")
  }

  def processFile(ci: Cipher, in: FileInputStream, out: FileOutputStream, mode: String): Unit = {
    val buffer = new Array[Byte](1024)
    var bytesRead = 0
    while ({bytesRead = in.read(buffer); bytesRead} != -1) {
      val obuf = ci.update(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
      if (obuf != null) out.write(obuf)
    }
    val obuf = ci.doFinal()
    if (obuf != null) out.write(obuf)
    in.close()
    out.close()
  }

  def decryptData(inputFilePath: String, outputFilePath: String): Unit = {
    val inp = new FileInputStream(inputFilePath)
    val out = new FileOutputStream(outputFilePath)
    val privateKey = getPrivateKeyFromCert(jksFileLocation, jksPwd, privatePwd, certAlias)
    println("Private key generated from cert " + privateKey)
    val AESKey = decryptAESKeyFromFile(inp, privateKey)
    println("AES key retrived from encrypted data " + Base64.getEncoder.encodeToString(AESKey.getEncoded))
    val iv = new Array[Byte](16)
    inp.read(iv)
    println("iv length during decrypt " + iv.length)
    println("iv data during decrypt ")
    iv.foreach(println(_))
    val ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv)
    val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding")
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, AESKey, ivParameterSpec)
    processFile(cipher, inp, out, "decrypt")
  }

  def printPublicKeyToFile(filePath: String): Unit = {
    val publicKey = Base64.getEncoder.encodeToString(getPublicKeyFromCert(jksFileLocation, jksPwd, certAlias).getEncoded)
    println(s"Public key is - $publicKey")
    val file = new File(filePath)
    if (!file.exists()) file.createNewFile()
    val out = new FileOutputStream(publicKeyFilePath)
    out.write(publicKey.getBytes)
  }

  def getPublicKeyFromCert(jksFileLocation: String, jksPwd: String, certAlias: String): PublicKey = {
    val inputStream = new FileInputStream(jksFileLocation)
    val keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS")
    keyStore.load(inputStream, jksPwd.toCharArray)
    keyStore.getCertificate(certAlias).getPublicKey
  }

  def getPublicKeyFromFile(inputPath: String): PublicKey = {
    // Function to read the public key stored ib the form of file and convert to PublicKey type
    val inpData = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(inputPath)))
    val publicBytes = Base64.getDecoder.decode(inpData)
    val keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicBytes)
    val keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA")
    keyFactory.generatePublic(keySpec)
  }

  def printDataRefIdToConsole(): Unit = {
  }

  def getIVFromFile(in: FileInputStream): IvParameterSpec = {
    val iv = new Array[Byte](16)
    in.read(iv)
    new IvParameterSpec(iv)
  }

  def generateAESKey(): SecretKey = {
    // Function to generate 256 bit AES symmetric key
    val keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES")
    keyGen.init(128)
    keyGen.generateKey()
  }

  def getEncryptedAESKeyBytes(publicKey: PublicKey, AESKey: SecretKey): Array[Byte] = {
    // Function to encrypt AES key with public key
    val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding")
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey)
    cipher.doFinal(AESKey.getEncoded)
  }

  def generateIV(): (IvParameterSpec, Array[Byte]) = {
    // Function to generate initialization vector for AES encryption
    val iv = new Array[Byte](16)
    new SecureRandom().nextBytes(iv)
    (new IvParameterSpec(iv), iv)
  }

  def getPrivateKeyFromCert(jksFileLocation: String, jksPwd: String, privatePwd: String, certAlias: String): PrivateKey = {
    val inputStream = new FileInputStream(jksFileLocation)
    val keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS")
    keyStore.load(inputStream, jksPwd.toCharArray)
    keyStore.getKey(certAlias, privatePwd.toCharArray).asInstanceOf[PrivateKey]
  }

  def decryptAESKeyFromFile(in: FileInputStream, privateKey: PrivateKey): SecretKeySpec = {
    val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding")
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey)
    val bytes = new Array[Byte](512)
    println("Reading decrypted bytes for AES key")
    in.read(bytes)
    val keyBytes = cipher.doFinal(bytes)
    new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES")
  }
}
```

Below is what I am doing

Encryption

1. Read public key stored in file.
2. Generate secret key which is symmetric. This will be used to encrypt and decrypt the file.
3. Read the input file, encrypt AES secret key with public key using RSA and write it to encrypted file, write iv, and then finally encrypt the actual data using AES secret key and write it to encrypted file

Decryption

1. Extract private key from cert
2. Read the encrypted file and decrypt first 512 bytes of data with private key - this will give me decrypted AES secret key.
3. Read next 16 bytes iv from encrypted file.
4. Read the remaining content and decrypt it using AES secret key.

Observations

1. Encryption is successful
2. Secret can be matched after encryption and decryption
3. iv is matched after encryption and decryption
4. Decryption is successful - BUT COULD NOT BE MATCHED WITH INPUT DATA

Comment: The issue is in your "def decryptData" function: "cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, AESKey, ivParameterSpec)". I would change it to **DECRYPT_MODE** :-) [I did not check the rest of your code but this is obvious]

Comment: Thanks for the catch. Its working now !